# How to fix python discord bot none type error?

Tags: python, discord

I've been looking and researching but I can't find a direct answer for this.

Here's the code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print("gaming")
   user = client.get_user(381870129706958858)
   await user.send('eee')
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
user = await client.fetch_user(381870129706958858)
await user.send('eee')
```

`Get_user()` searches for the user in cache and sometimes it might not be there. Then you have to use `fetch` which makes requests for data from Discords API.

*Three different methods for getting Discord data (channels, users etc.):*

> **Fetch** asks discord for that channel (makes and http request to discord). **Get** looks through the cache. In case you don't know, that means that discord.py keeps a list or some other datatype of channels, users, guilds, etc in memory so it doesn't have to ask discord all the time and it's faster. **Utils.get** works with what you give it and doesn't looks through the cache (unless what you give it is the cache).

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/fzv061/discordpy_whats_the_difference_between_fetchget/)

Comment: thanks man, this really helped :D is there a way to look at the entirety of the discord api and its functions? I want to learn more...

Comment: [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) you can find documentation for the Discord.py library.

Comment: thanks again man